# IIS mod/extension to support eXtended Server-Side Includes (XSSI)?

Tags: apache, iis, asp-classic, server-side-includes

I've been working with a designer that wants ot bring some content developed on Apache to IIS. The content however makes use of XSSI. I have not been able to find out if IIS can support such things. Perhaps its named something else on Windows/IIS? A sample of this is shown below:

```
<!--#config timefmt="%Y%m%d" --> 

<!--#if expr="$DATE_LOCAL < 20090311" --> 

<P>This will be shown before my birthday in 2009 
<!--#endif --> 
<!--#if expr="$DATE_LOCAL >= 20090311" --> 

<P>This will be shown during and after my birthday in 2009 
<!--#endif -->
```

It seems I could replicated this behaviour with classic .ASP but I dont know if this is the common practice for this sort of processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSSI is not supported by any version of IIS, you have to write code such as .asp or asp.net code to accomplish this sort of thing.